# If $x_k \leqslant y_k$ for all $k \geqslant m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ then $x \leqslant y.$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ be represented by the Cauchy sequences of rationals $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ respectively. If $x_k \leqslant y_k$ for all $k \geqslant m$ then $x \leqslant y.$

My textbook proved the above proposition while also remarking that the converse is false. I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample, if anyone could show me one I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ where $x_k = \frac{1}{k}$

and $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ where $y_k = -\frac{1}{k}$

$y = x = 0$ so $x \leqslant y$ is true.

now $x_k \leq y_k$ for none of the $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Thus we have a counterexample for the converse of the statement

Answer (score 1):

Note that the converse is true if $x<y$. In fact, suppose that  $x<y$, then $y-x>0$. Hence, for $\varepsilon=\frac{y-x}{2}$ there is $N$  such that if $n\geq N$ then $\left|y_{n}-y\right|<\frac{y-x}{2}$  and $\left|x_{n}-x\right|<\frac{y-x}{2}$.
Therefore, $x_{n} \leq y_{n}$ for all $n\geq N$.

Thus the contraejempo exists when we have $x=y$, for example, $\left(x_{n}\right)$ given by $x_{n}=x+\frac{1}{n}$  and $y_n=y-\frac{1}{n}$ with $x=y$.